# Unable to remove xr:uid attribute in namespace of a xml file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a task to remove some unwanted items from a xml file using C# and I am stuck with removing the `xr:uid` element in the xml file shown below.

Please let me know how to remove this element from the xml file?

(note : xr:uid element is at the end of the worksheet tag in the xml shown below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
mc:Ignorable="x14ac xr xr2 xr3" 
xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" 
xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" 
xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2" 
xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3" 
xr:uid="{8E28DF99-D6F7-4FB7-8192-149FA1C4DA53}">
</worksheet>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if this attribute exists, and then simply remove it

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"test.xml");
var node = doc.ChildNodes[1];


if (node.Attributes["xr:uid"] != null)
    node.Attributes.Remove(node.Attributes["xr:uid"]);
```